Vim switches buffers autonomously
I've just encountered a new undesired behavior in Vim, possibly related to the :make command: I have a makefile with a check target that runs a Gtk4 GUI app that I'm working on. When I dismiss the app (by clicking the red 'X' button on the frame, the buffer that was open before running :make check is replaced with an empty buffer named with the current date ('2024-10-6').
If, instead of :make check I run make, then :!./demo (the name of the built executable) everything runs correctly (no mysterious buffer switching).  What might be the cause of that? How can I avoid this?
Context: MacOS 15.0 on M2 Macbook, Vim - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled Sep 11 2024 06:07:33) macOS version - arm64, Included patches: 1-727
Similar behavior with both Vim and MacVim r180.

If the output of :make check fits (or is close to) the current errorformat, then it may be parsed into a quickfix list with a strange buffer name (which would then be jumped to). You can see if this occurs with :cc, :cwindow, or :copen.
Ideas:

change the program output (either as Makefile redirection or some other way)
use a different 'efm' in such cases (possibly via :compiler …)
:make! check to avoid jumping to the first error


I've been using Vim since version 5 and never knew about make!  Thanks!

@RadlyEel try :help :make ;)
